# Continuity of inverse function at endpoints

Tags: analysis, continuity

*Let $f$ be a strictly increasing continuous function on a closed interval $[a, b]$, let $c = f(a), d = f(b)$, and let $g:[c, d] → [a, b]$ be its inverse. Then $g$ is a strictly increasing continuous function on $[c, d]$.*

How can it be shown that $g$ is continuous at its endpoints $c$ and $d$? I am not familiar with one-sided continuity arguments...

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing continuous funcion on a closed interval it means that it is invertible with continuous inverse. Let $g$ its inverse so we have that $g(c)=f^{-1}(c)=a$ and $g(d)=f^{-1}(d)=b$

Comment: @DavideMarano *If $f$ is strictly increasing continuous function on a closed interval it means that it is invertible with continuous inverse.* Why?

Comment: Write down the epsilon-delta definition (or whatever definition your course uses) for continuity. This should be a follow-your-nose rearrange-the-symbols problem.